# Show content only if logged in

Tags: php, html

Hello I have a question. I have set up my login system with cookies and it works. But I wonder is there a more clean version of doing this.

```
<?
include('../config/db_config.php');

$username = $_COOKIE['user'];
$password = $_COOKIE['pass'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE isadmin = 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password'])
    {
        //User entered correct username and password
        echo("ALLOW");
    }
    else
    {
        //User entered incorrect username and password
        echo("DENY");
    }
}
?>
```

You see I want all my content to be shown ONLY if I am logged in as admin. So what, now only way of doing this would be ECHO'ing out my HTML/PHP/Javascript instead of echoing ALLOW because if I just include("somepage.php") there that page would still be avialable for usage without logging in, and even if I do same check there I still would be ECHO'ing out everything.

Comment: for the love of all that is security **read @MainMa's post**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Why are you loading every user, then comparing the username and the password? Wouldn't be easier to load a single user matching the username and the password?
- Loading a single user will allow to remove the `while()`.
- In PHP, **don't** use `mysql_query`; **do** use PDO (if need, google for it to know why it's better).
- Check your input (quite optional here, I agree).
- **Do never** store passwords in plain text format.

You can probably do something like (I haven't used PHP/PDO for years, so the code may be inexact):

```
if (strlen($username)> 128)
{
    // Something wrong. The username is too long.
}

$hash = sha1($password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('if exists(select * from users where isadmin = 1 and username = :username and password = :password) select 1 else select 0');
$sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 128);
$sth->bindParam(':password', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
$sth->execute();
$isFound = $sth->fetchAll();
if ($isFound)
{
    // User entered correct username and password.
    echo 'ALLOW';
}
```

Comment: I think you might be missing a bracket in that `if exists(...` part. Also, according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), `sha1($password);` will be a 40 char string, not 20.

Answer (score 4):

You could set a session variable on your login page (or any page that checks the login) that stores whether or not they're logged in and it will persist across pages. Then you can simple wrap your admin html in an if statement like so:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['isAdmin'] == true) {
?>
<p>My admin html</p>
<?php
} else {
?>
<p>My non-admin html</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

To save the info in a session, just add this to the part where you have `echo("ALLOW");`:
    $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = true;

You'll also want to add `session_start();` to the top of the script.

Comment: I think this is probably the simplest way to accomplish what the OP is after. I'm not a PHP person, but if this is like ASP then it will only render the html when the conditions are met, which only shows content to admins.

Comment: Okey thank you I didn't know about this, now I have it clear.

Comment: You're welcome. You can extend it by saving an access variable as an int to have multiple levels of access or whatever you please. Also, you might want to look into querying only for the username/password rather than getting all users. Other people have mentioned this below and don't ever forget about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do something like that only once, when the user first accesses the page, and then set a $_SESSION['is_admin'] or something for the rest of the time, so that you don't have to make an extra db call each page.

Comment: If rights are changed, I'm assuming that there is a log in procedure and the session variable could be set then.

Answer (score 0):

You could always put your "somepage.php" *above* the document root. This is a common way of preventing direct execution.

For example, if your webserver looks like 'project/public_html/index.php' put your admin-only include in 'project/somepage.php' then reference it using something like include("../somepage.php").

Obviously this will need adjustment according to the real paths you use.